# How to connect Firefox debugger to window with WebDriver extension?

Tags: javascript, debugging, firefox, selenium, webdriver

Firefox gives an option called "Browser Toolbox" for developers which allows debugging extension, e.g. set breakpoints and inspect variables. When I connect in a normal FF window, I get alert about incoming debugging connection. When I accept it, the browser toolbox is opened and I can play with extensions code.

I'm using WebDriver for my tests and I'm not satisfied with performance. (e.g. clicking element takes ~500 ms) so I want to debug the Javascript (as apparently this is where delay takes place). However when I call Browser Toolbox there is no alert about debugging connection, but there is only new window - white, empty screen which doesn't load anything no matter how long I wait.

What is the reason that WebDriver-controlled window doesn't setup debugging connection? Is there any workaround for it?

Comment: what type of selenium bindings are you using?

Comment: Java, the most up-to-date 2.45

Answer (score 0):

By default , Webdriver launches a default instance of Mozilla i.e without any add on.
So, to achieve your goal,Create a firefox profile, install particular add on(like for debugging). 
In your webdriver code, add firefox profile and give path of your new firefox profile folder. Now, when, a browser will get launch, it will open your mentioned profile and which would be having your debugger as well

Comment: I believe you are wrong, Firefox WebDriver package comes with webdriver.xpi addon which is always installed after WebDriver is instantiated. Take a look here http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-firefox-driver/2.44.0/org/openqa/selenium/firefox/internal/NewProfileExtensionConnection.java#NewProfileExtensionConnection and inspect how addWebDriverExtensionIfNeeded() method is called and what does it do. I have even opened Firefox addons settings while running test and verified that the webdriver addon is active.

Comment: And what I want is not install any other "debugging addon" but rather start debugging session to examine default addon used by Firefox WebDriver.